# Only part of contents of JScrollPaneVisible after adding elements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I wrote a basic gui that handles a chat service. Inside the frame is a JScrollPane that houses a panel to which I add JTextAreas. Only the first few of these JTextAreas are visible even when I scroll to a different part. The only way for me to be able to see another part is by resizing the entire window.

```
                if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        conversationName.setText(Contacts.getSelectedValue());
                        HashMap<String, Object> temp = conversationList.get(Contacts.getSelectedIndex());
                        ArrayList<HashMap> tempMessageArray = (ArrayList<HashMap>) temp.get("messageArrayList");
                        textContainer = new Panel();
                        textContainer.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        textContainer.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                        textContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                        //reverse the message array
                        for(int i = 0, j = tempMessageArray.size() - 1; i < j; i++) {
                            tempMessageArray.add(i, tempMessageArray.remove(j));
                        }
                        ActiveNumber = (String) tempMessageArray.get(0).get("number");
                        for(int i = 0; i < tempMessageArray.size(); i++){
                            int direction = 1;
                            if(tempMessageArray.get(i).get("direction").equals("Sent")){
                                direction = 0;
                            }
                            showMessage((String)tempMessageArray.get(i).get("body"), direction);
                        }
                        textContainer.setVisible(true);
                        chatWindow.setViewportView(textContainer);
                        chatWindow.updateUI();
                    }

                });         

            }
```

Here is the class that shows each message

```
private void showMessage(final String m, int u){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        //System.out.println(m);
                        RoundJTextField tempText = new RoundJTextField();
                        tempText.setText(m);

                        tempText.setEditable(false);
                        switch(u){
                        case 0: //Texts send from user
                            tempText.setBackground(uiColor);
                            tempText.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
                            tempText.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
                            tempText.setPreferredSize(tempText.getPreferredSize());
                            textContainer.add(tempText);
                            break;
                        case 1: //Texts sent to user
                            tempText.setPreferredSize(tempText.getPreferredSize());
                            tempText.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
                            tempText.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
                            tempText.setMaximumSize(tempText.getPreferredSize());
                            textContainer.add(tempText);
                        //  textContainer.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
                            break;
                        }

                        chatWindow.revalidate();

                    }
                }
                );
    }
```

Comment: Don't call `chatWindow.updateUI();`, it's not doing what you think it is. Look at calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on `textContainer` instead of `chatWindow`

Comment: No, it scrolls to the bottom automatically, the problem is that none of the elements at the bottom are visible. If I scroll to the top, the elements are visible there. If I stay at the bottom I have to resize to see them.

Comment: If that fails to resolve the issue, consider providing a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem

Comment: I tried calling `repaint` and `revalidate` on `textContainer`but I still had the same problem.

Comment: [No runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no possible answer that isn't guess work and conjectuor

Comment: When I changed the `textContainer` to a `JPanel` instead of just a `panel` it worked.

Comment: <face palm? Of, you were using `java.awt.Panel`, yeah, that would cause an issue